# how to use camouflage x into y

Tags: grammar

> He camouflaged his dog into a bush by placing little shrubs around the
> dog.

Doesn't sound right. Is there a better way to say this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking because it's not clear if you're saying you camouflaged your dog ***as*** a bush, making your dog actually look like a bush, or you're saying you camouflaged your dog ***in*** a bush, like by placing a bush or shrubbery in such a manner that it surrounds him, making him difficult to see. To be clear, one actually alters his appearance to match his surroundings and the other doesn't alter his appearance but merely makes him less visible by altering his surroundings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Camouflage is used to make an object appear to be another object or to make an object blend into its surroundings.    You can camouflage something **by** doing something to it, as Brad suggests.  You can also camouflage something **as** something else **by** doing something to it.

> He camouflaged his dog **by** placing little shrubs around it.

> He camouflaged his dog **as** a shrub **by** covering it in moss and pine boughs and sternly saying, "Stay!"

You can hide your dog **in** a bush.  If you are a powerful wizard you might be able to turn your dog **into** a bush but that's a more literal transformation.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you could also say you camouflaged your dog **in** a bush.  It's probably not how I would say it, it's a bit unclear, but with a little context I would certainly understand it.

Answer (score 0):

*He camouflaged his dog into a bush by placing little shrubs around the dog*. Is an incorrect sentence. It is also hard to grasp the exact concept that you are intending to relate. I would suggest this sentence maybe appropriate.

> He camouflaged his dog, by placing little pieces of bush around it.